# How to prove Cohen forcing does not add unsplit real?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

This is an exercise of a forcing lecture notes. The problem is:
Assume $\mathcal{A}$ is an $\omega$-splitting family in $V$. Then $V^\mathbb{C}\models$"$\mathcal{A}$ is $\omega$-splitting".
Here $\mathbb{C}$ is the Cohen forcing. $\mathcal{A}\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ is $\omega$-splitting
means that for every countable sequence $B_i\in[\omega]^\omega$, there is $A\in\mathcal{A}$ such that for all $i$, $|A\bigcap B_i|=|B_i\setminus A|=\omega$.
To prove this, the key lemma is: if $\dot A$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-name for an infinite subset of $\omega$, there exists countable sequence $B_i=B_{\dot A,i}\in [\omega]^\omega$ such that whenever $C\in [\omega]^\omega$ splits all $B_i$, $C$ splits $A$ in the forcing extension.
Let $\mathbb{C}=\{s_i,i\in\omega\}$, I tried to construct $B_i$ as this: $m\in B_i$ iff $\exists p\le s_i(p\Vdash m\in \dot A)$. Does this $B_i$ work? I can't prove it.

Comment: A while ago someone had sent me the following notes found [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/personen/khomskii/ST2013/bogotalecture.pdf). What you are looking for is corollary $1.12$. Unforunately, it's proof is left as an exercise but you can prove it relatively easily by modifying the proofs of lemma $1.9$ and $1.10$.

Comment: @Shervin Sorouri: Thanks for your comment, this is the notes I am reading, but I can't construct $B_i$ in lemma 1.11. I have updated the question and explained my ideas.

Comment: Yes, it works. Show that the sets $D_n = \{p \in \mathbb{C} : \exists m >  n ( p \Vdash m \in \dot A \cap C)\}$ and the sets $E_n = \{ p \in \mathbb{C} : \exists m >  n ( p \Vdash m \in \dot A \setminus C)  \}$ are dense for every $n$.  If $q$ is an arbitrary condition, say $q = s_i$, then use the assumption that $C$ splits $B_i$ to find an extension in $D_n$. Same for $E_n$.

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks too much! Now I understand.